# Haskell: large number of long-running threads taking up big STACK space

Tags: haskell, concurrency, ghc

A server program keeps long-running TCP connections with many clients. Each client connection is served by a thread created with `forkIO`. The server takes up a lot of memory when running, so naturally I did a profiling to hunt down possible space leaks. However, with around 10k clients (hence 10k threads), the result shows that a major portion of the heap is actually STACK allocated by threads. If I understand correctly, this is not surprising since the stack of a thread starts with 1k by default, and increases by 32k chunks. As these are long-running threads, these memory won't be GCed.

My question: *STACK takes up too much space, is there a way to reduce it?*

I had some thoughts on this: previously I could use the event notification APIs from GHC to write the program without using threads, however it seems this option is no longer possible as GHC has stopped exporting some of the event handling functions such as `loop`. On the other hand, such change means a major shift in concurrency model (threads vs events), which is very undesirable since the Haskell threads are simply so enjoyable to work with. Another way that came to my mind is to split/rewrite the threads so that one thread does all the handshaking+authentication stuff, creates a new thread and then exits. The new thread, which will keep looping, hopefully doesn't require more STACK space. However I'm not sure if this idea is correct or doable.

[image: profiling]

Comment: How about just reducing the stack chunk size (from the RTS help: `-kc<size> Sets the stack chunk size (default 32k)`)?

Comment: Above we see 300M for STACKS. Dividing this by 10k threads, we get ~36k per thread. Not so bad, just ~1 chunk per thread -- from these numbers, @ReidBarton's suggestion looks quite promising.